# multidimensional name selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input

So I've got a ***huge*** array like this:

```
var enemy = {
    'level1' : {
        creature :
        {
            creature_name : {
                 'Goblin' : {
                    info: {
                        'c_name' : 'Goblin',
                        'HP' : '20',
                        'damage' : '3',
                        'loot' : [
                            {name: 'a wooden sword'   , item: 'weapon'  , value: 2}, 
                            {name: 'a golden necklace', item: 'amulet' , value: 1},
                            {name: 'a pair of boots'  , item: 'boots'  , value: 1},
                            {name: 'some cloth legs'  , item: 'legs'  , value: 3},
                            {name: 'a cloth helmet'  , item: 'helm'  , value: 2}
                        ]
                    }
                 },
                 'Cow' : {
                    info: {
                        'c_name' : 'Cow',
                        'HP' : '10',
                        'damage' : '1',
                        'loot' : [
                            {name: 'a wooden sword'   , item: 'weapon'  , value: 2}, 
                            {name: 'a golden necklace', item: 'amulet' , value: 1},
                            {name: 'a pair of boots'  , item: 'boots'  , value: 1},
                            {name: 'a cloth helmet'  , item: 'helm'  , value: 2}
                        ]
                    }
                 },
                 'dragon' : {
                    info: {
                        'c_name' : 'Cow',
                        'HP' : '300',
                        'damage' : '300',
                        'loot' : [
                            {name: 'an almighty dragon sword'   , item: 'weapon'  , value: 200}, 
                            {name: 'a dragon tooth', item: 'amulet' , value: 30},
                            {name: 'a pair of dragon boots'  , item: 'boots'  , value: 60},
                            {name: 'a dragon helmet'  , item: 'helm'  , value: 60}
                        ]
                    }
                 },

            }

        },
    },
    'level2' : {
        'skelleton' : {
            'HP' : '40',
            'damage' : '5',
            'loot' : [
                {name: 'a bone'   , item: 'weapon'  , value: 1},
                {name: 'a warriors helmet'   , item: 'helm'  , value: 4} 
            ]
        }
    }

};
```

and when I select the *creature* I want I need to call it like this:

`enemy.level1.creature.creature_name.dragon.info.c_name`

Now I want to be able to choose an enemy by a `input box` or something like that.
But I can't figure out *how* I insert that value in the `enemy.level1.creature.creature_name.dragon.info.c_name`

I tried using `enemy.level1.creature.creature_name.+ input_value + .info.c_name`

But that doesn't seem to work. Must be a simple solution for this?

Comment: `enemy.level1.creature.creature_name[input_value].info.c_name`

Comment: Thanks! gonna try it out :)

Comment: `enemy.level1.creature.creature_name[input_value].info.c_name`

Comment: That isn't an array.

Comment: It is not working, it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined. I think because it is creature_name.dragon.info.c_name and not creature_name["dragon"].info.c_name. any help? @Pointy

Comment: `creature_name["dragon"]` means exactly the same thing as `creature_name.dragon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is an object not an array.  You can set object properties in multiple ways.  One way would be like:

```
var myObj = {
  foo: {
    value : "foo"
  },
  bar: {
    value: "bar"
  }
}

myObj["foo"] = "123";
```

In your case you object is bigger but the process is the same:

```
enemy.level1.creature.creature_name[input_value].info.c_name = "whatever name";
```

where input value is one of the valid properties of creature_name, ie "dragon":

```
enemy.level1.creature.creature_name["dragon"].info.c_name = "whatever name"
```

Comment: It is not working, it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined`. I think because it is creature_name.`dragon`.info.c_name and not creature_name["`dragon`"].info.c_name. any help?

Comment: @GetOn you'll have to strip the spaces out of the string; the property name `dragon` with no spaces is not the same as ` dragon ` with spaces.

Comment: trim your value like:  var input_value = " dragon ";  then enemy.level1.creature.creature_name[input_value.trim()].info.c_name = "whatever name";

Comment: is there anything else you need help with....I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

When having variable name as the hash element, to access, instead of the `.dot` notation, you can use the `[]` notation.

So

```
enemy.level1.creature.creature_name[input_value].info.c_name
```

Should get you what you want.